# Как с помощью регулярных выражений достать два числа из строки?

Tags: python, re

У меня есть строка: '/randomNumber 0-1' мне надо достать два числа из этой строки (тире ставится для обозначения диапазона). Получение чисел из строки (до тире и после него) у меня вызвало некоторые трудности, так как я не очень знаком с модулем **re**. Вот отрывок кода, в котором я пытаюсь получить эти два числа, в строке 6,7 мне нужно записать числа в переменные, но получение этих чисел у меня вызвывает трудности, так как числа могут быть любые (десятизначные, отрицательные):

```
 1  import re
 2  from randomizer import randomNumber
 3
 4  answer = input()   # здесь вводится '/randomNumber "___"-"___"'
 5
 6  firstNumber = re.  # cюда надо записать
 7  secondNumber = re. # эти числа
 8
 9  response = randomNumber(firstNumber, secondNumber) # здесь числа передаются в функцию
10
11  print("",answer, answer[:13], "", firstNumber, secondNumber, sep="\n") # здесь выводится всё, делаю это только для теста.
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне их достать?

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @MaxU  отредактировал

Comment: `firstNumber, secondNumber = re.findall(r"\d+", answer)`

Answer (score 0):

Можно не думать над регулярками и просто разбить строку

```
firstNumber = answer.split(" ")[1].split("-")[0]
secondNumber = answer.split(" ")[1].split("-")[1]
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Вам бы оптимизацию кода сделать. эдак вы два раза делаете сплит для каждого числа.